# How to resolve 404 error from AWS API Gateway when url does not contain trailing slash?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, aws-api-gateway, reverse-proxy, openapi

I've created an API on AWS API Gateway. I've used this to proxy to a static app, e.g. called sample-app, that I've deployed to netlify.

The openapi configuration for it is attached below.

- https://sample.com/apps/sample-app/ works fine and I can see the app that I had deployed to netlify.
- https://sample.com/apps/sample-app gives me a blank page. On the console, it shows an error message: `net::ERR_ABORTED 404`

My questions are:

- Why does this not work?
- How can I get API Gateway to just add the /?
- Or, are there any better alternatives?

```yaml
openapi: "3.0.1"
info:
    title: "sample-api"
    version: "2020-04-29T23:24:23Z"
servers:
    - url: "https://sample.com"
paths:
    /apps/sample-app/{proxy+}:
    x-amazon-apigateway-any-method:
        parameters:
        - name: "proxy"
            in: "path"
            required: true
            schema:
            type: "string"
        x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        uri: "https://sample-app.netlify.app/{proxy}"
        responses:
            default:
            statusCode: "200"
        requestParameters:
            integration.request.path.proxy: "method.request.path.proxy"
        passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
        httpMethod: "ANY"
        cacheNamespace: "2ns27y"
        cacheKeyParameters:
            - "method.request.path.proxy"
        type: "http_proxy"
    /apps/sample-app:
    x-amazon-apigateway-any-method:
        responses:
        "200":
            description: "200 response"
            content:
            application/json:
                schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Empty"
        x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        uri: "https://sample-app.netlify.app/"
        responses:
            default:
            statusCode: "200"
        passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
        httpMethod: "ANY"
        type: "http_proxy"
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this? We occasionally see an intermittent issue where it 404s without a slash. Redeploying usually fixes it.

Comment: Nope. I used a nginx server to proxy requests.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're using a HTTP API or a REST API, but if you're using a HTTP API, you could setup a `$default` route as a catch all.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-routes.html#http-api-develop-routes.default

Once your `$default` route is setup, your https://sample.com/apps/sample-app should work.